# Sort array object based on another array in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i sort and rearrange an array that looks like this

```
fields = [
  {
    uid: '2c2162cc-37d0-f1e3-96c2-6d9ccb50f38d',
    field: new ObjectId("627f816d8443318c6aaa1220"
  },
  {
    uid: '2aa60f96-135b-e179-2b46-516c87a877cc',
    field: new ObjectId("6283cb3ca573a56e11587c46"),
  }
]
```

to match the arrangement of this array:

```
order = [ '6283cb3ca573a56e11587c46', '627f816d8443318c6aaa1220' ]
```

Here is the output I’m looking for:

```
[
{
    uid: '2aa60f96-135b-e179-2b46-516c87a877cc',
    field: new ObjectId("6283cb3ca573a56e11587c46"),
  },
  {
    uid: '2c2162cc-37d0-f1e3-96c2-6d9ccb50f38d',
    field: new ObjectId("627f816d8443318c6aaa1220"),
  }
]
```

findIndex and sort but I am very confused

```
fields.sort((a: any, b: any) => order.indexOf(a.field) - order.indexOf(b.field)) // It does not work
```

Comment: Do both arrays always have the same length? Or could it happen, that the Object-Array (the one you want to sort) has more entries than the array of objectIds?

Comment: Does  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1129270/1901635  help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `sort` method on the array. And then compare the index of `field` on the order array.

```js
const data = [
{
    uid: '2aa60f96-135b-e179-2b46-516c87a877cc',
    field: "6283cb3ca573a56e11587c46",
    value: 'test val 6'
  },
  {
    uid: '2c2162cc-37d0-f1e3-96c2-6d9ccb50f38d',
    field: "627f816d8443318c6aaa1220",
    value: ''
  }
]

const order = [ '6283cb3ca573a56e11587c46', '627f816d8443318c6aaa1220' ];

data.sort((a,b) => order.indexOf(a.field) - order.indexOf(b.field));
console.log(data);
```

Notice: `ObjectId` class is not defined here, so I changed it to string here for simplicity.

Comment: Its not working for me. Should i a.field conver objectid

Comment: @ŞahinErsever ObjectId class is not defined here, so I changed it to string here for simplicity. What is ObjectId class definition?

Comment: data.field: new ObjectId("627f816d8443318c6aaa1220" from mongoose

Comment: @ŞahinErsever you should be able to use data.sort((a,b) => order.indexOf(a._id.toHexString()) - order.indexOf(b._id.toHexString()));

Comment: `.toHexString()` it worked thank you very much